# How to reset Mathjax span id

Tags: javascript, mathjax

Is it possible to reset the MathJax-Span-Id?

I want to highlight different parts of formulas, but i load several latex formulas dynamically without reloading the page with `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, "somename"]);`
. Because of that the ids keep incrementing and i can't determine which id i'd have to choose to highlight the correct part of the formula.

Normally the spans start with ids like `#MathJax-Span-1` to `#MathJax-Span-40`, but after loading some formulas i get ids like `#MathJax-Span-715`.

Is there any way to set the id back to zero to properly select the correct divs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\cssId{name}{math}` to set the id for the subexpression given by `math` to be `name`.  That way it is constant, and you can refer to it directly.  E.g.

```
\cssId{term1}{x^2} + \cssId{term2}{3x} - \cssId{term3}{5}
```

would let you refer to the x^2 via the css ID `term1`, the x via `term2` and the constant via `term3`.

Comment: Thanks. This is way better than my original approach and it works perfectly fine, too. Don't know why i didn't see this in the MathJax docu.